# Unable to set file_field element using xpath

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

Html code is as follows:

```
<li>
   <form action="/en/pune/dsf/media/create" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <div style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: inline;">
      <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="DD9PUpCMWTGs66fHEZutO+9RFjcf68xH+T9DMXv1JnA="/>
    </div>
    <div class="media_upload_submit">
      <span class="icon-camera"/>
     <span class="al">Add photos</span>
    </div>
      <input class="media_image_file" data-track="photo_upload,spot_page,user" name="media[image]" type="file"/>
  </form>
</li>
```

I have tried using

```
@browser.file_field(:xpath, "//input[@type='file' and @class='media_image_file']/").set "Complete file path name"
```

but I get the following error:

```
Failure: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //input[@type='file' and @class='media_image_file']/ because of the following error:
```

I have tried using many different ways but get different errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a extra `/` after `..and @class='media_image_file']/"`. Remove it and write like :

```
 @browser.file_field(:xpath, "//input[@type='file' and @class='media_image_file']")
```

Comment: I have tried removing the extra `/` and now the error has changed `Failure: undefined method ``set' for #<Watir::Hidden:0xbaf8988>: ./lib/contact_jo
b.rb:23:in `run'``

Comment: Yes the error points to a hidden element and I have made sure that the html that I have posted is the correct one, things work good manually. Need to find a way using javascript as you have suggested.

Comment: @cage You need to use selenium-webdriver method `execute_script`.